# Dedup node_modules for a number of Vue applications

Tags: duplicates, vuejs3, node-modules

As a teacher I frequently have to look at students projekcts. A couple of courses deal with a Vue3 application and I end up with multiple similar if not equal `node_modules` folders for each students project. Is there away to prevent duplication of the contents of all these folders?

Comment: Take a look at [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/)

Comment: Thanks @Duannx _pnpm_ seems to work using symlinks (which would be the way to go) but they all point to a `.pnpm` within the __same__ node_modules. Is it me doing something wrong?

Comment: EDIT: missed the `pnpm config set...` setup.

Comment: It works but I had to make sure the projects are on the same device as the pnmp-store

Comment: What do you mean by "the projects are on the same device"? I thought they were all on your machine.

Comment: @Duannx on the same device as the pnpm-store.

Comment: ...and on the same drive

Comment: I don't see any problem when you need to keep all your projects in the same drive. But there another approach is that you can ask your students to publicize their projects on GitHub and [access it directly via stackblitz](https://developer.stackblitz.com/guides/user-guide/importing-projects#import-from-github)